# Django proxy model with additional model fields?

Tags: python, django, design-patterns, model, proxy

I'm writing a Django app that works like a newspaper.  I have articles and then I have customized versions of those articles that appear in certain contexts.  So, I could have a version of an article that appears on the front page of the newspaper that has a shorter version of the article's original headline.  So I have:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    """ A newspaper article with lots of fields """
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    # Lots of fields...
```

I'd like to have a `CustomArticlè object that is a proxy for the` Articlè, but with an optional alternative headline:

```
class CustomArticle(Article):
    """ An alternate version of a article """
    alternate_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    @property
    def title(self):
        """ use the alternate title if there is one """
        if self.custom_title:
            return self.alternate_title
        else:
            return self.title
            
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
    
    # Other fields and methods
```

Unfortunately, I can't add new fields to a proxy:

```
>>> TypeError: Abstract base class containing model fields not permitted for proxy model 'CustomArticle'
```

So, I could do something like this:

```
class CustomArticle(models.Model):
    # Other methods...
    
    original = models.ForeignKey('Article')

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if hasattr(self.original):
            return getattr(self.original, name)
        else:
            return super(self, CustomArticle).__getattr__(name)
```

But unfortunately, `__getattr__` doesn't seem to work with Django models.  The fields in the `Article` class could change, so it isn't practical to create a `@property` method for each one in CustomArticle. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Clarification on the workflow that I am trying to achieve: a writer creates an Article. Later, editors can create one or more CustomArticles from that preexisting Article for use in different contexts (ie, a version of the headline for the frontpage, a version for a callout somewhere else, etc)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this might work for the `__getattr__`:

```
def __getattr__(self, key):

    if key not in ('original', '_ original_cache'):
        return getattr(self.original, key)      
    raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (self.__class__.__name__, key))
```

Comment: for the conditional lookup, this avoids recursion.

Answer (score 1):

What about making CustomArticle a subclass of Article? Django models do support inheritance! Have a look at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance

Comment: I've looked into doing that, but I'm not sure how I would connect CustomArticle to a particular Article such that its ptr_id would always point to an existing Article in the database.

Comment: django will create a OneToOneField (a kind of ForeignKey) from the child to the parent model. This means you'll get the usual referential integrity constraints on that field. If you are using django<1.3, whenever you delete an Article instance, you will delete the referencing CustomArticle instance. From django 1.3 you should be able to specify the desired behavior upon deletion of an Article instance.

Comment: You should also verify, assuming you need such a feature, that django will let you create a CustomArticle from an already existing Article instance (that, speaking in terms of your problem's domain, corresponds to the possibility of transforming an Article into a CustomArticle)

Comment: the work flow is like this: a writer creates an Article.  Later, editors can create one or more CustomArticles from that preexisting Article for use in different contexts.  My experience with parent/child relations has been that Django won't let me create a CustomArticle from an existing Article.

Comment: "one or more" means you cannot make CustomArticle use table inheritance. You need to manually handle this with a many-to-one relationship.

Comment: as for overriding __getattr__ for django models, I need to dive a bit deeper in the topic :-(

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
class CustomArticle(models.Model):
    # Other methods...

    original = models.ForeignKey('Article')

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.original, name)
```

Comment: That seems to work about 90% of the time, but there are still situations that seem to cause it to go into an infinite loop and break (notably in the Django Admin interface).